How can I obtain the rotated surface code from the original unrotated one?
I am trying to understand the equivalence between the original planar surface code and the rotated version.
Looking at Tomita and Svore's paper (2014), they say

"The number of qubits [from original unrotated surface code] can be
reduced while maintaining the same code distance by rotating it
clockwise by 45 degrees and removing the four corner data qubits"

. My questions:

Is possible to make this notion more precise? (Why are we allowed to simply do this and be sure the pictures are equivalent?)

What procedure should one follow to remove the stabilizers (i.e. turning the weight-3s into weight-2s, and deleting some of them)?

In terms of their equivalence, how should I interpret the fact that the unrotated surface code has more stabilizers than the rotated one?

Besides being less resource intensive, are there any performance advantages of the rotated code?


I have been also checking some old papers from Bombin and Martin-Delgado (this one and this one) as well as Kovalev and Pryadko's work. While I appreciate the answers should be in there, I am failing distill a simple explanation from their discussions.

I find this explaination useful: https://arthurpesah.me/blog/2023-05-13-surface-code/
